# Plone FSD custom classifications not showing on aggregate

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm using the latest FSD product and when I make a new classification two strange things happen.

a) The classification shows this strange text right before the name, in the screen shot the weird text is Pascal Code

b) The classification doesn't show on the view mode of the Directory.

Things I've tried:

Making a new classification, Copying one of the defaults that works and renaming it (This just makes it have a new strange name and doesn't work. The classification in question here has about 10 people attached to it.

here are the screen shots

http://cl.ly/image/0P3b3M1G1j2q

http://cl.ly/image/2Z010Y2W3s1z

Thanks

Comment: What is Plone FDS? I don't find neither on google

Comment: @keul he means https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.fsdsimplifier/1.3.

Comment: Problem a looks alt text from missing images. Can you check that with the browser's developer tools? (Right click, inspect, check if it's an `img` tag)

Answer (score 0):

FSD is Products.FacultyStaffDirectory.

The reason this is happening is that FSD is calling folder_icon.gif for the classification icon.  Folder_icon.gif became folder_icon.png in Plone, so FSD can't find the icon.  The fastest way to fix this is to go to your plone ZMI, choose portal_skins, choose plone_images, folder_icon.png and click customize.  This will create a copy of folder_icon.png in the portal_skins/custom folder. Browse to the custom folder and rename folder_icon.png to folder_icon.gif.  You can also fix the code in the FacultyStaffDirectory Classification content type.

Reindexing your catalog should get your missing classification to show up.